# System.Unauthorizedaccesexception while reading and writing an xml using Windows 8 xaml C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am working on windows 8 xaml C# apps, I am trying to read a song xml and append new node to it. The code is:

```
StorageFolder sf;
sf = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
StorageFile file = await sf.GetFileAsync(strSongName);
var item = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
IRandomAccessStream raStream;
IOutputStream outputStream;
DataWriter writer;
var lc = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var infolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(infolder.Path);
StorageFile file1 = await folder.GetFileAsync("songxml.xml");
var filetest = await file1.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
Stream inStream = filetest.AsStreamForRead();
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(inStream);
string content = xdoc.ToString();
raStream = await file1.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWriteUnsafe);
outputStream = raStream.GetOutputStreamAt(0);
writer = new DataWriter(outputStream);
StringBuilder outputText = new StringBuilder();
outputText.Append(content.ToString());
```

I get a System.Unauthorizedaccessexception while running this code

Comment: At which line exactly do you get the exception?  Please show the stack trace of the eception.

Answer (score 0):

My psychic debugging powers tell me you need to mention in your capabilities that you'll be accessing the Music known folder, and that you haven't done that yet.

[image]

Am I right?

Comment: I have already enabled the music library,video library and documents library in capabilities

Comment: this is the stack trace of the exception:::::  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Media1.Player.<backButton_Click_1>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\sakthijananit\Desktop\latest medi abuild\Media1-Copy\Media1\Player.xaml.cs:line 280

Answer (score 0):

I have...well actually had the same problem. Given the date of your last comment, I guess you've figured it out by now. Nevertheless, maybe there will be others that visit this thread, so... 
I guess you should make sure that you've added the extensions you expect to Declarations->Supported Declarations->File Type Associations.
Maybe this limitation is not there, when using the Music Library, but for the Documents Library (make case), this is exactly the case.

Edit: Make sure you backup the contents of the LocalState folder, because every change to the application manifest results in deleting your contents.

Happy coding